# Company best employee survey and sensitive data

Tags: database, security, encryption

Consider the problem bellow:

Every year we provide the best employee survey in our company. We want to automate this process(now we use some papers and a block box). It is easy to build a survey application but the main problem here is the privacy.
There are some requirements:

- User should be able to login
- User can give a vote for somebody only once
- The survey should be completely anonymous even for database administrator

I guess we can achieve this with some form of database encryption. But what should I do with the keys?

Comment: There is a lot of research into cryptographic voting systems. I doubt you will get a sketch of a solution that is secure and uses only common cryptographic primitives.

Comment: Do you need the results to be auditable and/or prevent a DBA from rigging the election?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, I do but only in simple form. I should be able to prove that nobody changes his vote for example

Comment: What is the reason to downvote or close the question?

Answer (score 1):

A (simple) idea to hide user ID from the DBA is to encode it in the DB using the user password as a cryto key. If the executable used for the survey is somehow protected from reverse-engineering, that would provide a basic level of identity protection.

An even simpler idea:

If you are allowed to keep some paper around, you can create and distribute "voting cards". Cards with a unique ID (say, 8 or 10 characters) are distributed randomly to voters, and instead of login with his/her real name, the voter uses his (secret) ID. That way, anonymity is guaranteed, and you can do the checks you want on the votes.

Comment: I guess a DBA and a developer are only one person, so this kind of protection doesn't work:)

Comment: Yes but the code can be audited / compiled / checked by another person. I the developper still has access to the code *after* auditing, there's no protection possible (I think).

Comment: but in the case the auditor is ф guy who knows everything about voices:)

Comment: The source code and binary are stored in a repo, so that anyone can check that the survey executable they're using has not been tampered with. To know a vote you have to have both the user password and a "cheating" voting program.

Comment: Also, the voting code could be a JS script served from a (protected) web server, internal or external depending on who you're trusting.

Comment: @kharandziuk I've added another idea in the answer.